# Error(3,34): PLS-00201: identifier XXX must be declared

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have this procedure in a Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production DB, bit I have this error everytime I try to recompile it. The procedure is a copy and paste from another DB, so there is now error, because in the other DB the package works properly... nevertheless I got this error:

```
Error(1,35): PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'P_COUNTRY_PLATS' without its specification
```

.

```
  create or replace PACKAGE "P_COUNTRY_PLATS" is

procedure createNew (p_msisdn IN lopes.country_plats.recipient_msisdn%TYPE
                    ,p_channel IN lopes.country_plats.channel%TYPE
                    ,p_message IN lopes.country_plats.message%TYPE
                    );
procedure createNew (p_msisdn IN lopes.country_plats.recipient_msisdn%TYPE
                    ,p_channel IN lopes.country_plats.channel%TYPE
                    ,p_message IN lopes.country_plats.message%TYPE
                    ,p_request_date IN lopes.country_plats.request_date%TYPE
                    ,p_action_history_id IN lopes.country_plats.action_history_id%TYPE
                    );
procedure createNew (p_msisdn IN lopes.country_plats.recipient_msisdn%TYPE
                    ,p_channel IN lopes.country_plats.channel%TYPE
                    ,p_message IN lopes.country_plats.message%TYPE
                    ,p_request_date IN lopes.country_plats.request_date%TYPE
                    ,p_action_history_id IN lopes.country_plats.action_history_id%TYPE
                    ,p_ac_scheduled_action_id IN lopes.country_plats.ac_scheduled_action_id%TYPE
                    );

procedure getNextMsgToSend (p_channel IN lopes.country_plats.channel%TYPE
                           ,p_ip_address IN OUT VARCHAR2
                           ,p_message IN OUT lopes.country_plats.message%TYPE
                           ,p_msg_id IN OUT lopes.country_plats.country_plats_id%TYPE
                           );
procedure getNextMsgToSendByImei(p_imei IN VARCHAR2, p_message IN OUT VARCHAR2, p_msg_id IN OUT NUMBER);

procedure setStatus(p_msg_id IN NUMBER, p_status IN VARCHAR2);

procedure cancel_scheduled_actions;
procedure cancel_scheduled_actions(p_msg_id IN number);
end;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY "P_COUNTRY_PLATS" is
procedure createNew (p_msisdn IN lopes.country_plats.recipient_msisdn%TYPE
                    ,p_channel IN lopes.country_plats.channel%TYPE
                    ,p_message IN lopes.country_plats.message%TYPE
                    )
is
begin
  createNew(p_msisdn, p_channel, p_message, sysdate, null, null);
end;

procedure createNew (p_msisdn IN lopes.country_plats.recipient_msisdn%TYPE
                    ,p_channel IN lopes.country_plats.channel%TYPE
                    ,p_message IN lopes.country_plats.message%TYPE
                    ,p_request_date IN lopes.country_plats.request_date%TYPE
                    ,p_action_history_id IN lopes.country_plats.action_history_id%TYPE
                    )
is
begin
  createNew(p_msisdn, p_channel, p_message, p_request_date, p_action_history_id, null);
end;

procedure createNew (p_msisdn IN lopes.country_plats.recipient_msisdn%TYPE
                    ,p_channel IN lopes.country_plats.channel%TYPE
                    ,p_message IN lopes.country_plats.message%TYPE
                    ,p_request_date IN lopes.country_plats.request_date%TYPE
                    ,p_action_history_id IN lopes.country_plats.action_history_id%TYPE ,
                    p_ac_scheduled_action_id IN lopes.country_plats.ac_scheduled_action_id%TYPE
)
is
  PsdRetryNbroutgoing_psd number;
begin
  PsdRetryNbr := of_owner.p_ru.getPsdRetryNbr(p_msisdn);

  of_owner.p_db_trc.trc(1007, '-'||p_channel||'-'||p_msisdn||'-'||p_message||'-'||p_request_date||'-'||p_action_history_id||'-'||p_ac_scheduled_action_id||'-'||PsdRetryNbr);

  insert into lopes.country_plats
  (country_plats_id,channel,recipient_msisdn,message,request_date,status,action_history_id, ac_scheduled_action_id, remaining_retry_nbr) values (
   lopes.SEQ_COUNTRY_PLATS_ID.nextval
  ,p_channel
  ,p_msisdn
  ,p_message
  , p_request_date
  ,'R'
  ,p_action_history_id
  ,p_ac_scheduled_action_id
  ,PsdRetryNbr
  ); 
end;                    

procedure getNextMsgToSend(p_channel IN lopes.country_plats.channel%TYPE
                           ,p_ip_address IN OUT VARCHAR2
                           ,p_message IN OUT lopes.country_plats.message%TYPE
                           ,p_msg_id IN OUT lopes.country_plats.country_plats_id%TYPE
                           )

is
begin
  select op.country_plats_id, op.message, of_owner.p_ru.getRemoteUnitCurrentIP(recipient_msisdn)
  into p_msg_id, p_message, p_ip_address
  from lopes.country_plats op
  where ( (op.status ='R') 
       or ( (op.status = 'P') 
        and (op.outgoing_date+(of_owner.p_ru.getPsdRetryDelay(op.recipient_msisdn)/(60*24)) <= sysdate) 
          ) 
        )  
  and rownum=1
  order by request_date asc;

  update lopes.country_plats
  set outgoing_date = sysdate
     , status = decode(remaining_retry_nbr, 0, 'F', 'P')
     , remaining_retry_nbr = remaining_retry_nbr-1
  where country_plats_id = p_msg_id;

exception when no_data_found then
  p_msg_id := -1;
  p_ip_address:= '';
  p_message := '';
end;

procedure getNextMsgToSendByImei(p_imei IN VARCHAR2,
                           p_message IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                           p_msg_id IN OUT NUMBER
                           ) is
  p_vehicle_id number(10);
  p_msisdn varchar2(50);
begin

  p_msg_id := -1;
  p_message := '';

  select msisdn, vehicle_id 
  into p_msisdn, p_vehicle_id
  from of_owner.remote_unit, of_owner.vehicle 
  where remote_unit.imei = p_imei 
  and remote_unit.remote_unit_id = vehicle.remote_unit_id(+);

  begin  
    select op.country_plats_id, op.message
    into p_msg_id, p_message
    from lopes.country_plats op
    where ( (op.status ='R') 
         or ( (op.status = 'P') 
          and (op.outgoing_date+(of_owner.p_ru.getPsdRetryDelay(op.recipient_msisdn)/(60*24)) <= sysdate) 
            ) 
          )  
    and op.recipient_msisdn = p_msisdn
    and rownum=1
    order by request_date asc;

    update lopes.country_plats
    set outgoing_date = sysdate
       , status = decode(remaining_retry_nbr, 0, 'F', 'P')
       , remaining_retry_nbr = remaining_retry_nbr-1
    where country_plats_id = p_msg_id;
  exception when others then
    null;
  end;
  -- Check if garmin message to send  
  if (p_msg_id=-1) and (p_vehicle_id is not null) then
    p_msg_id := of_owner.p_gu_message.getNextMessageToSend(p_vehicle_id, p_message);
    if (p_msg_id is null) then
      p_msg_id:=-1;
    end if;
  end if;

exception when no_data_found then
  p_msg_id := -1;
  p_message := '';
end;

procedure setStatus(p_msg_id IN NUMBER, p_status IN VARCHAR2)
is 
begin

  update lopes.country_plats
  set status = decode(p_status, 'S', 'S', decode(remaining_retry_nbr, 0, 'F', 'P'))
  where country_plats_id = p_msg_id;    

end;

procedure cancel_scheduled_actions is
begin
     delete from lopes.country_plats
     where status = 'R'
     and ac_scheduled_action_id is not null;
end;

procedure cancel_scheduled_actions(p_msg_id IN number) is
begin
     delete from lopes.country_plats
     where country_plats_id = p_msg_id;
end;

end P_COUNTRY_PLATS;
/
```

Comment: Put a `/`  character on a new line after the `END;` statement terminating the package specification. Then at the end of the package body change it to `end PLATS;` and put another `/` on the following newline.

Comment: HUH? Title: **Error(3,34): PLS-00201: identifier XXX must be declared** In the message body: **Error(1,35): PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'P_COUNTRY_PLATS' without its specification**. Different error code (201 vs 304), different error message - obviously the two errors are of different nature from each other, different place in the code (line 3, position 34 vs. line 1, position 35). So: Which is it? And how did this happen? ("This" being you posting a message about one error, as described in the body, and giving the title with an completely different error.)

Comment: @en Lopes - So which one should we tackle - PL-00201 or PLS-00304 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` character is a terminator for a PL/SQL block and your script is missing them.

Change:

```
end;


create or replace PACKAGE BODY                     "P_COUNTRY_PLATS" is
```

To:

```
end;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY                     "P_COUNTRY_PLATS" is
```

and change the final:

```
end;PLATS
```

to:

```
end P_COUNTRY_PLATS;
/
```

Comment: Did you notice the mismatch between this guy's title and what's in the message body?